# GSON: .isJsonNull() question

Tags: json, null, gson

I am reading in a JSON file (using Google's `GSON`). One of my tests checks program's behavior in event file a given key is missing.

```
JsonElement value = e.getAsJsonObject().get(ENVIRONMENT);
```

My expectation is that when .get(ing) this key, i would get `null`. Turns out i do. When i `.get(ENVIRONMENT)`, value returned is `null`.

When i test it, i actually get a "**not null**". Weird, considering, GSON's javadoc says "**provides check for verifying if this element represents a null *value* or not**"

```
if (value.isJsonNull()) {
    System.out.println("null");
} else {
    System.out.println("not null");
}
```

Please help me better understand this.

Comment: have you tried printing the implementing class returned by e.getAsJsonObject().get(ENVIRONMENT); ?

Comment: Is it a null reference or a JsonNull reference?  I'm assuming it's a JsonNull reference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Never mind my first answer below.  I'd read the question too quickly.

It looks like this is a simple case of the documents lying -- or at least being misunderstood.  Fortunately, code does not lie so easily and Gson is an open source project.

Here's `JsonObject.get(String)`:

```
  /**
   * Returns the member with the specified name.
   *
   * @param memberName name of the member that is being requested.
   * @return the member matching the name. Null if no such member exists.
   */
  public JsonElement get(String memberName) {
    if (members.containsKey(memberName)) {
      JsonElement member = members.get(memberName);
      return member == null ? JsonNull.INSTANCE : member;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and here's where `members` is populated:

```
  /**
   * Adds a member, which is a name-value pair, to self. The name must be a String, but the value
   * can be an arbitrary JsonElement, thereby allowing you to build a full tree of JsonElements
   * rooted at this node.
   *
   * @param property name of the member.
   * @param value the member object.
   */
  public void add(String property, JsonElement value) {
    if (value == null) {
      value = JsonNull.INSTANCE;
    }
    members.put($Gson$Preconditions.checkNotNull(property), value);
  }
```

Calls to add to `members` are made for every member defined in the Java class -- it's not based on what's in the JSON.  (For those interested, the `visitFieldsReflectively` method in `ReflectingFieldNavigator` populates members.)

So, I suppose the confusion is surrounding the meaning of "member" in the clause "if no such member exists".  Based on the code, I gather that the author of the JavaDoc was referring to a member defined in the Java class.  To the casual user of the Gson API -- like myself -- I assumed that "member" referred to an object element in the JSON.

Now, is this issue clear?

====

First answer based on quick read of question (retained for useful links):

A `null` reference is not a `JsonNull` value.  `(value == null)` is not the same as `value.isJsonNull()`.  They are very different.

The docs describe that the call to [`JsonObject.get(String)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#get-java.lang.String-) returns "[n]ull if no such member exists."  They do not say that `JsonNull` is returned.

The call to `JsonElement.isJsonNull()` is not checking whether the `JsonElement` reference is a `null` reference.  In fact, if it were a `null` reference, calling a method on it would throw a `NullPointerException`.  It's checking whether it's a [`JsonNull`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonNull.html) instance.

Answer (score 2):

isJsonNull() handles the case where the json element exists but has the json null value. get() returning Java null means that the element does not exist. Here's a simple example:

Json:

```
{
    "testElement": null
}
```

Java Code:

```
if (json.get("testElement").isJsonNull())
{
    System.out.println("testElement is json null value"); //This will print.
}
if (json.get("nonExistentElement") == null)
{
    System.out.println("nonExistentElement does not exist"); //This will print.
}
```

References:

> JsonObject: public JsonElement get(String memberName) Returns the member with the specified name. Parameters: memberName - name of the
> member that is being requested. Returns: the member matching the name.
> ***Null if no such member exists***.

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or
> false or ***null***, or an object or an array. These structures can be
> nested.

https://www.json.org/json-en.html