# Why JsonNull in GSON?

Tags: java, gson

The docs say the [JsonObject#get](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#get-java.lang.String-) method returns null if no such member exists. That's not accurate; sometimes a `JsonNull` object is returned instead of `null`.

What is the idiom for checking whether a particular field exists in GSON? I wish to avoid this clunky style:

```
jsonElement = jsonObject.get("optional_field");
if (jsonElement != null && !jsonElement.isJsonNull()) {
    s = jsonElement .getAsString();
}
```

Why did GSON use `JsonNull` instead of `null`?

There is an answer for [**what**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6256907/519951) are the differences between `null` and `JsonNull`. In my question above, I'm looking for the reasons why.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Gson, presumably, wanted to model the difference between the absence of a value and the presence of the [JSON value `null`](http://json.org/) in the JSON. For example, there's a difference between these two JSON snippets

```
{}
{"key":null}
```

your application might consider them the same, but the JSON format doesn't.

Calling

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(); // {}
jsonObject.get("key");
```

returns the Java value `null` because no member exists with that name.

Calling

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.add("key", JsonNull.INSTANCE /* or even null */); // {"key":null}
jsonObject.get("key");
```

returns an instance of type `JsonNull` (the singleton referenced by `JsonNull.INSTANCE`) because a member does exist with that name and its value is JSON null, represented by the `JsonNull` value.

Answer (score 7):

I know question is not asking for a solution, but I came here looking for one. So I will post it in case someone else needs it.

Below **Kotlin extension code** saves the trouble of checking for `null` and `isJsonNull` separately for each element

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement
import com.google.gson.JsonObject


fun JsonObject.getNullable(key: String): JsonElement? {
    val value: JsonElement = this.get(key) ?: return null

    if (value.isJsonNull) {
        return null
    }

    return value
}
```

and instead of calling like this

```
jsonObject.get("name")
```

you call like this

```
jsonObject.getNullable("name")
```

Works particularly great in nested structures. Your code eventually would look like this

```
val name = jsonObject.getNullable("owner")?.asJsonObject?.
    getNullable("personDetails")?.asJsonObject?.
    getNullable("name") 
    ?: ""
```