# Does Java have a wrapper type for Null?

Tags: java, null, wrapper

I need to distinguish between a property having a null value, and a property not existing at all.  I could use a map, but for performance reasons, I am trying to use a fixed size array.

In the array, I could use `null` to indicate when a property does not exist at all.  But, for a property that does exist and is null valued, is there a standard way to represent it in an array?

I thought of keeping a static member, e.g.

```
class MyClass {

    private static final Object NULL = new Object();   // null wrapper
    
    private Object[] m_arr = new Object[10];

    // 'i' represents the index of a property in the array

    boolean exists(int i) {
        return m_arr[i] != null;
    }

    Object value(int i) {
        if( !exists(i) ) throw new NullPointerException();   // does not exist
        if( m_arr[i] == NULL ) return null;

        // ... handling for other data types ...
    }
}
```

Another possibility for representing null might be an enum?

```
class MyClass {
      ...
      enum Holder {
            NULL
      }
      ...
      // to check for a null value use m_arr[i] == Holder.NULL
}
```

Comment: No. Your valued `NULL` is just fine (it's also private for good). `Optional.empty()` might be a good candidate too since it is a global singleton (I hope, right?) -- so that you could simply make your `NULL` to point at `Optional.empty()` and not even create a dumb new object. Additionally, throwing a `NullPointerException` might be not  a very good choice: `NoSuchElementException` is more suitable here.

Comment: Sounds like you are over-complicating something. Are you sure this isn't an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Having trouble wrapping my mind around this statement cause "exist" and "null" are opposites..."But, for a property that does exist and is null..."

Comment: as long you keep it consistent (where is the "nulling code"??), do as you like! :):) Probably a "map" or (at least) two arrays (one with "properties" one with "values") would be better... suited (for whatever you try to accomplish)

Comment: It's fine: the difference the OP can see is like a difference in JavaScript between `null` (we know it has no value, say `Optinal.empty()` or `NULL` for the OP) and `undefined` (we have no idea what it is at all as it may not exist too, `null` for the OP). The OP is actually doing a marker object representing a null-value object saving on `Optional.of` boxes (and it is just fine as long as it is a private implementation).

Comment: but (in java) having `private static final Object NULL = new Object();` the only use of it can be something like `NULL.toString()` or hashCode or so... (hacking NPE) ...for all other cases, `null` is good enough.

Comment: No, the OP's idea is to make a distinction between a `null` reference and an object known to be "empty". Consider the `NULL` object in the OP's code as a marker for such a special value.

Comment: i don't understand this distinction, but it depends on who/how sets them.. (2 arrays!?!? one for "properties" one for "values" ...if property is not there we don't need to look at the value....and otherwise: value can be null/empty/""/NULL/NIL/{})

Comment: the "guy",  who "sets the NULLS" can also: set `null`s and/or(!) shrink array! ;)

Comment: Consider two maps, say `Map<K, V>` and `Map<K, Optional<V>>` (assume there is nothing like a "key exists" method). For the first map, `map.get("not-existing-key")` would return a `null` -- the result is ambiguous for null and "no value". For the second map, returning a `null` would mean the map is not aware of such a value, but returning `Optinal.empty()` (or any other marker) would mean that the map is aware of the value and considers it empty explicitly. The same goes to the difference between `undefined` and `null` in JavaScript.

Comment: ...having map, we would not discuss this here: if key is null: then "the property doesn't exist", otherwise we can look at the value.

Comment: I used `Map` only for demo purposes explaining how to distinct between null and no value. Here is another "why" there is a distinction between presence and absence of the value (I could remember this example quickly because I used to work with JSON a lot): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114293/why-jsonnull-in-gson (@Bohemian in his answer also shed light for a similar purposes using Jackson). Feel the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Optional](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html), eg

```
private Optional<String> myField;
```

There are three states. Here's how to handle them:

```
myfield = Optional.of("foo"); // attribute has non-null value
myfield = Optional.empty();   // attribute is present, but null
myfield = null;               // attribute is not present
```

---

Jackson (ie Spring boot) json deserialization supports this out of the box, which is very handy for handling `PATCH` methods that require the distinction between a json key being specified but null and not specified.

Comment: The designers of `Optional` discourage fields and parameters of `Optional` type. And a collection of `Optional` deserves all the ridicule that it's sure to receive. The null object pattern is a much better alternative.

Comment: The designers of `Optional` implemented it as lip-service to functional programmers and clearly do not understand how to actually use it. This is an excellent use case for optional types. At the type-level, this answer will actually *enforce* that we only do safe things with our data structure and that we check whether the value exists *before* dereferencing a null or doing something unintended.

Comment: I guess that using `Optional` like that is fine for several cases (as @Bohemian also is suggesting it might be valid to have a difference between null and no value at all for PATCH). But I would say that the OP would also save on using unnecessary `Optional` wrappers not requiring each element to be wrapped in another optional box.

Comment: @erickson Optional works in all cases and its intention is clear. I have implemented Optional fields in a DTO at a major bank's PATCH endpoint, which has worked flawlessly and passes every functional and performance we could conceive.

Comment: This is abuse of Optional IMO. The expectation by most developers would be that a reference to an Optional is inherently **not** nullable. You should never have to check whether a reference to an Optional is null before calling methods on it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo No. `myField = null` means you have to first do a null check, *then* you get some help with enforcement if the value proves to be non-null.

Comment: @Bohemian I have seen some frameworks that do similar things to support partial updates, whether with optional or an equivalent custom, or in other languages with property delegates. But that's where you have a framework reading these fields. I wouldn't want to see humans writing code that looks like `if (myField != null) myField.ifPresentOrElse(x::setField, x -> x.setField(null))` Null-checks and `Optional` just don't belong together.

Comment: @erickson I understand a bit better now. I was initially responding only to your comment. I still strongly disagree with the "don't use `Optional` as a field or in a collection" advice for the reasons I already stated. But yes, I'm inclined to agree with you that an `Optional` containing a `null` or an `Optional` which is itself a `null` is an abomination. You make an excellent point in that regard. "Don't use `Optional` and `null` together" is a reasonable guideline.

Comment: @erickson The unavoidable fact is the implementation must support 3 states. Optional is one way to achieve this, and it comes with the JDK, so no code to write. Yes, you must check for null then empty, but *any* implementation must to 2 tests to distinguish the 3 states; why not a null check as one of them.

Comment: @Michael ditto my comment to erickson

Comment: The answer to your rhetorical "why not a null check as one of them": because it should be unintuitive to anyone who's worked with Optional. IntelliJ will warn you if you try to compare an Optional to null, and likewise if you try to assign null to a variable declared as Optional. I imagine that's not the only static analyzer which would complain about this. It warns you because that's not how 99% of people use it. We should aim to write code which minimizes the number of "WTF?" moments and your solution doesn't do that.

Comment: @Michael and yet my project works just fine, and has never had any NPE or other similar errors. How can that be? Thorough testing is the answer to your objections. That will catch any code that doesn’t deal with such fields properly.

Comment: I never said it didn't work so that's a strawman. I said it was unintuitive. Thorough testing does not make unintuitive code intuitive.

Comment: @Michael You make a good point - having to check that an Optional is null is not intuitive; the intention of Optional is to not have to null check. To be fair and less cavalier, when I used it I wrote a utility method to overwrite the stored object with the patch payload, respecting the 3 states of fields. Once that operation was done, the DTO was discarded. This approach contained the weirdness to one place, which was thoroughly unit tested, and devs working elsewhere in the project were not exposed to this unconventional usage of Optional.

Comment: That's what I was getting at with having "a framework read these fields," and, "you wouldn't want humans writing code" like that. Hidden away somewhere, sure, optional or a similar three-state wrapper is fine. But not as part of a public API for developers to code against.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Java have a wrapper type for Null?

No.

But how I'd solve this problem means you don't need to a wrapper: just maintain a set of the indices which represent "explicit" null values.

```
class MyClass {
    private Object[] m_arr = new Object[10];
    private Set<Integer> presentButNullIndices = new HashSet<>();

    // 'i' represents the index of a property in the array

    Object value(int i) {
        if (m_arr[i] == null && !presentButNullIndices.contains(i)) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        // ... handling for other data types ...
    }

    // just an example of how to maintain the set
    void insert(int i, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
             presentButNullIndices.add(i);
        }
        else {
             presentButNullIndices.remove(i);
        }
        m_arr[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Worst case, the space complexity doubles, but that's only for clients which make heavy use of null values. `contains` on a set is O(1)

I'd also consider just prohibiting null values in the first place. Some map implementations do that and I've never found myself in a situation where I wish they didn't.

Answer (score 0):

NO... but, Java now has `Optional` which could be viewed as the same. You could also create a class to represent a null object, which can be done following the "Null Object Pattern". I wrote about this in a blog: https://www.professorfontanez.com/2020/04/the-beauty-of-null-object-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons [ObjectUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html) has a [NULL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#NULL) field for this purpose, if you don't want to define your own.

Comment: Didn't know about this field. Thanks!